# Suppose A is an m-by-n matrix with $A\ne0$. Prove that the rank of A is 1 if and only if ....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with $A\ne 0$. Prove that the rank of A is $1$ if and only if there exist $(c_1,...,c_m) \in {F^m}$ and $(d_1,...,d_n) \in {F^n}$ Such that ${A_{j,k}}$ = ${c_j}{d_k}$ for every $j = 1,...,m$ and every $k = 1,...,n$.
It is problem from linear algebra done right(3.F.11)

I think for firs part if we take all entries $1$ and all i,j ${c_{j}=1}$ , ${d_{k}=1}$  it will work.
but for other direction??

Comment: The rank of $A$ is equal to the dimension of the row space. A dimension one vector subspace is the span of a single basis vector.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a proof of one of the implications and leave the other one for you. Assume that $A \neq 0$ and $\text{rank} A = 1$. That means that the column space of $A$ is one-dimensional. Let $\mathbf{c}$ be a vector spanning $\text{Col} (A)$. Then there exists constant $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$ so that

$$A = [d_1 \mathbf{c} \quad d_2 \mathbf{c} \quad \cdots \quad d_n \mathbf{c} ] = \mathbf{c}[d_1 \quad d_2 \quad \cdots \quad d_n]=\mathbf{c} \mathbf{d}^T.$$

$A = \mathbf{c} \mathbf{d}^T$ is equivalent to $A_{j, k} = c_j d_k$ (see why?), which proves the first implication.

Comment: what is $\mathbf{c} \mathbf{d}^T$

Comment: It is the product of the vectors $\mathbb{c} = (c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_m$ and the transpose of $\mathbb{d}$ as it is defined above. I have now also corrected a minor typo.

Comment: $$A = [d_1 \mathbf{c} \quad d_2 \mathbf{c} \quad \cdots \quad d_n \mathbf{c} ] = \mathbf{c}[d_1 \quad d_2 \quad \cdots \quad d_n]=\mathbf{c} \mathbf{d}^T.$$ actually I hadn't seen this kind of representation can you explain it please?

Comment: I think the easiest way to see the is by simply writing out the product with the components and perform the matrix multiplication. You should also observe that in general we have 

$$AB = A[b_1 \quad b_2 \quad \cdots \quad b_n] = [Ab_1 \quad Ab_2 \quad \cdots \quad Ab_n]$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r$ is a basis for the image of $A$ (aka the column space), then for any $\mathbf{x} \in \operatorname{Domain}A$,

$$A\mathbf{x} \in \operatorname{Span}\{\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r\} \iff A\mathbf{x} = f_1(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}_1+\dots+f_r(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}_r$$

for some coefficients $f_i(\mathbf{x})$ that depend on $\mathbf{x}$.

I claim, and you should check, these coefficients $f_i(\mathbf{x})$ are linear functionals in $\mathbf{x}$. (i.e. linear maps from $\mathbf{F}^n \to \mathbf{F}$).

If you have a linear functional $f : \mathbf{F}^n \to \mathbf{F}$ then it's associated matrix is a row vector. Because, by definition, the matrix is $[f(\mathbf{e}_1),\dots,f(\mathbf{e}_n)]$. If I call this matrix $\mathbf{w}^\top$ then $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}$.

So if $A$ has rank $r$, then I can write $A = \sum_{i = 1}^r \mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{w}_i^\top$. So we can check:

$$A\mathbf{x} = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^r \mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{w}_i^\top \right) \mathbf{x} = \sum_{i = 1}^r \mathbf{v}_i(\mathbf{w}_i^\top\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^r f_i(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}_i. $$

$r = 1$ is the exercise in question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A=M(T)$, where $T \in L(V,W)$ and $rank(A)=1$. Then we have $$rank(A)=dim(range\ T)=1$$
Let $w_1,...,w_m$ be a basis of W, there exists a vector $w$ such that $range\ T=span(w)$ with $w=\sum_{j=1}^m c_jw_j$, where $c_1,...,c_m \in F$. Thus,
$$Tv_k=d_kw=\sum_{j=1}^m c_jd_kw_j $$ where $d_k \in F, k=1...n$, which implies $A_{j,k}=c_jd_k$.

Conversely, assume there exists $(c_1,...,c_m) \in F^m$ and $(d_1,...,d_n) \in F^n$, and there exists a pair of bases on V and W such that
$$T(v_k)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_jd_kw_j=d_k\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_jw_j$$,
which implies that $range\ T=span(\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_jw_j)$. Thus, $rank(A)=dim(range\ T)=1$.